Late 1990s to early 2000s movie or TV series that involved a talking goose/duck
I'm trying to identify a movie or TV series I've seen as a child/teen (so in late 1990s / early 2000s, though this could be an older production that got re-broadcasted). I'd gladly get some help, here's what I can remember:

the protagonist is a woman, who's got (two? step?) sisters
she's a knight, which is indicated in the story as being abnormal (something about "only males should be knights")
it's in a fantasy / medieval setting, with castles, knights, princesses and fairy tales
there's a talking goose (or a duck) that keeps the protagonist company

The most clearer memory I've got must be near the end. Everyone is getting ready for the last battle. The protagonist is talking to her (step?) sisters which are also donning armours, though they do it because they're out of choice (and something about character arc, I seem to remember they were against women becoming knights or something).
The sisters find the armour suit awkward and try to make them more comfortable by stuffing them with cotton.
It's been itching my brain for the past decade, I've done a couple of research but "talking goose" doesn't seem to be a helpful keyword... Thanks for your help!

Live action or animated? Do you remember anything about ethnicities or hair colors? Were the knight and her sisters blonde-haired, blue-eyed, and white-skinned, for example?

Live action. The Knight and sisters were all white-skinned, I don't remember the hair or eye colour

Might this be Fantaghirò or Cave of the Golden Rose, first film of the Fantaghirò series?

For many centuries two kingdoms have been at war with each other, though neither side remembers what the war is for. In one of the kingdoms, the warrior king has three daughters: Catherine, Caroline, and Fantaghirò. Although Catherine and Caroline are well-behaved princesses, Fantaghirò is outspoken, and rebellious, and longs to fight in battle. She constantly argues with her father and two sisters who disapprove of her behaviour.
Fantaghirò secretly learns to fight when she befriends the White Knight, a mysterious warrior whom she meets in the forest. As they are training, she briefly crosses paths with Romualdo, the newly crowned king ruler of the neighbouring enemy kingdom. Romualdo is enchanted by Fantaghirò's eyes but is unaware that they belong to the daughter of his sworn enemy.
Romualdo is tired of the war and sends an offer of a single duel to determine the outcome. Fantaghirò's father is told by the magical White Witch that only one of his daughters can win that duel. Seeing no other option, the King commands his three daughters to disguise themselves as male knights so they may fight Romualdo.
Fantaghirò relishes the opportunity and cuts her hair to look like a man, but Catherine and Caroline are fearful. While travelling to Romualdo's kingdom disguised as knights, the three sisters argue about the outcome of their mission, and Catherine and Caroline decide that their younger sister is the most qualified to win. Catherine and Caroline return to their father and Fantaghirò continues on her journey.
Fantaghirò eventually meets with Romualdo, who is confused when he recognises her eyes. After various attempts by Romualdo to discover the real identity of the knight by trickery, they eventually battle and Fantaghirò emerges victorious. However, she cannot kill him and returns home in shame. Fantaghirò's father, who is proud of what his daughter has achieved, forgives her. The King also allows Romualdo to continue to rule his people, on the condition that he marries one of the three princesses. Although at first Romualdo is hesitant to agree when he sees and recognises Fantaghirò, the two kiss happily and the realms are united after decades of war.

This wiki page mentions the talking goose, who continues to advise her through the film. Said goose is voiced by the same actress who plays the White Witch, who is known for shapeshifting into various animals. I'm not certain if it's actually directly implied that the Goose is the witch hiding as an animal.

Humiliated, the King sends Fantaghirò to work in the kitchen as a servant. There, she befriends a talking Goose.

Trailer



The goose show up around 2:13 of this video clip.

Found with a search for live action tv series female knight talking goose

This is it!
I didn't know it was an italian series (it was dubbed in my language), but as soon as I saw the poster on the wikipedia page you linked, I immediately recognized it.
I've watched the trailer, and most of it don't speak to me at all... Except around the 2:13 mark you've signalled as being the talking goose: I remember that scene when she rolls herself in the bandages. As well as the next scene when she closes her helmet.
Thank you so much!
